# Why does a skew-linear form on kG determine a triangular structure on k[G]?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

I'm trying to understand braidings on finite group representations. They are the same as quasitriangular structures on the group algebra $k[G]$. The original reference seems to be http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9706007.pdf. It is stated there [sic]:

> Teorem 3
>   Universal
>   $R$-matrix in the group algebra $k[G]$ of a group $G$
>   is defined by [...] by nondegenerated bimultiplicative $G$-invariant form
>   $\beta: \hat{A} \otimes \hat{A} \to k$.

The formula he gives is:
$$R = \frac{1}{\lvert A\rvert} \sum_{\substack{\chi_1, \chi_2 \in \hat{A}.\\g_1,g_2 \in A}}\beta(\chi_1,\chi_2) \chi_1(g_1) \chi_2(g_2) \cdot g_1 \otimes g_2$$

And then:

> Unitary $R$-matrix corresponds to the case of [...] skewsymmetric form.

"Unitary" here means $RR_{21} = 1 \otimes 1$, also known as "triangular", i.e. it gives a symmetric braiding.

Later in the proof, it only says:

> The direct cheking shows the equivalence of this condition to
>   skewsymmetricity of the corresponding form.

I can't see at all why a skewsymmetric $\beta$ makes $RR_{21} = 1 \otimes 1$ true. This is how far I get:

$$RR_{21} = \frac{1}{\lvert A\rvert^2} \sum_{\substack{\chi_i, \in \hat{A}\\g_i \in A\\i \in \{1...4\}}} \beta(\chi_1,\chi_2) \beta(\chi_3,\chi_4) \left(\prod_i \chi_i(g_i)\right) \cdot g_1g_4 \otimes g_2g_3$$

And now I'm supposed to insert $\beta(\chi_1,\chi_2) = \beta(\chi_2,\chi_1)^{-1}$ and suddenly all summands vanish except $1 \otimes 1$? It's just not happening.

Or maybe I'm not understanding what "skewsymmetric" is supposed to mean here?
There is an earlier bit where he says that the Markov element $u = S(R_{(1)})R_{(2)}$ satisfies $\chi(u) = \beta(\chi,\chi)$, but isn't the right hand side automatically 1?

Edit:
I'm learning that the following is probably relevant:
There is a quantity $Q = R R_{21}$ and a map $\Phi: kG \to k[G]$ given by $\Phi(f) = \sum f(Q_{(1)})Q_{(2)}$. If this map is an isomorphism, the braiding makes $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ into a modular category, if it's "trivial", the braiding is symmetric. But I don't see what trivial exactly means here.